# How to loop through an array of objects and find objects with same value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects and I want to loop through in a way that all the objects that have same value for name property, like first, third and last object has same value (person 1) for name property and total its amount.

like the result should be like:- person 1 - 434 (total amount)

```
const arr = [
  { name: "person 1", amount: 154 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 240 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 100 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 160 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 140 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 180 },
];
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. Here's the documentation [on loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: @Andy this is the one - https://js-wvnft6.stackblitz.io
although there were several attempts that I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest approach is using a simple [`for/of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement).

Create an `output` object, and then iterate over the array. On each iteration of the array of objects: if `output` doesn't already have a property key that matches the `name` of the current object create one by assigning it zero. Then increment that property's value with the current amount.

Note: I've used [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) (`??=`) here but `output[name] = output[name] || 0` would also work if your system doesn't currently support it.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "person 1", amount: 154 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 240 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 100 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 160 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 140 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 180 },
];

// Create an empty object
const output = {};

// Iterate over the objects in the array
// I've destructured the name and amount from
// the object (documentation below)
for (const { name, amount } of arr) {

  // If the output object doesn't have a property
  // key that matches the current object's name
  // create it by assigning it zero
  output[name] ??= 0;

  // Then increase its amount
  output[name] += amount;
}

console.log(output);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Hey, I know this is not something I should be asking on stackoverflow but as I am learning on my own and do not have money to take bootcamp or college and no one who could guide me. you seem to be an experienced person.

How do I get good with this kind of logic ? Is this something that I should keep on practicing or is there anything else too

Comment: Yes: practice and read. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) is a fantastic resource, but reading about code also has to balanced by writing code, and you will learn as you go along. Remember that JS ecosystem changes a lot so don't worry about learning _everything_ - you can't. Just take it one step at a time. @UnkownSomeone. You will hit bad patches, and want to give up - but don't lose hope. Every developer goes through stages like that, even the old ones like me :)

Comment: For example look at the first link in my answer re: loops. Understanding the nuances between each approach (some loops are meant for iterating over array, some on objects) is important so you don't build side-effects into your code.

Comment: I know about loops and I knew about `for/of` loop too, but currently I lack the ability to use my knowledge to solve a problem, I have been trying to solve this since morning I used several methods like map, forEach, reduce, for loop etc but nothing seemed to work then at the end I decided that I should ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array into an object that is keyed by name.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "person 1", amount: 154 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 240 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 100 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 160 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 140 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 180 },
];

const groupedByName = arr.reduce((acc, { name, amount }) =>
  ({ ...acc, [name]: (acc[name] ?? 0) + amount }), {});

console.log(groupedByName);
```

If you want to be more performant, as suggested in your linked article, you can use a `for...of` loop.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "person 1", amount: 154 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 240 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 100 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 160 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 140 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 180 },
];

const result = {};
for (const { name, amount } of arr) {
  result[name] = (result[name] ?? 0) + amount;
}
console.log(result);
```

If you knew about these patterns already, why did you ask the question in the first place? If you had an algorithm already and wanted to improve it, you can visit [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: ({ ...acc, [name]: (acc[name] ?? 0) + amount }), {})
I do not understand what is happening in this line, I do understand in parts but not as a whole like nullish coalescing.

Comment: And there's also the issue of the [`reduce/spread` anti-pattern](https://www.richsnapp.com/article/2019/06-09-reduce-spread-anti-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

I will not write your code for you; however, I am more than happy to point you in the right direction. Use a `for` loop to iterate through all the objects. Keep a global counter variable for each person/group.

In the `for` loop: Using the `name` property, figure out which counter to increment. Increment the counter variable by the number in the `amount` property.

After the `for` loop terminates, the counter variables will have your results. **Make sure your counter variables are declared *outside* the `for` loop; otherwise your variables will not be available in the global scope.**

Comment: I appreciate your help.

It's not like I did not try it by myself I hade been trying whole day. 

this is the code that I had wrote - https://js-wvnft6.stackblitz.io

but at the end I thought that I should ask for it's not good to waste time anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you might think of initially,

```
const arr = [
  { name: "person 1", amount: 154 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 240 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 100 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 160 },
  { name: "person 2", amount: 140 },
  { name: "person 1", amount: 180 },
];
let first = [];
arr.forEach((e)=>{
  first.push(e.name);
})

first.sort(); let person = [];
person.push(first[0]);
for(let i =1 ;i<first.length ; i++){
      if(first[i]!==first[i-1]){
        person.push(first[i]);
      }
}

let sum =0; let sumarr = [];
person.forEach(element => {
      arr.forEach(element2 => {
            if(element===element2.name){
              sum+=element2.amount;
            }
      });
      sumarr.push(sum); sum=0;
});

for(let i =0 ; i<sumarr.length ; i++){
  console.log(person[i] , sumarr[I]);
}
```